# explode() is not working as expected

Tags: php, string, web-scraping, explode

I want to explode this string:

```
$string = "WATER VALVE COMPLETE (5 PORT) Company: (US) Pools & Spas - SCP Manufacturer: CARETAKER C|O COVER POOLS INC Product Number: CTK-20-8609 Manufacturer Part #: 5-9-2000 U/M: EA Description: Caretaker 5-Port Water Valve, Complete";

$e = explode($string, "Company:");
```

But it is not working as expected, I want the part before Company. How can I modify my code, so that it explodes the string properly?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have the arguments both ways around with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) as you can have it with `implode()`. Look at the signature:

> array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )

And you see, that the delimiter is the first argument.

So this means:

```
$e = explode($string, "Company:");
```

change the argument order to:

```
$e = explode("Company:", $string);
```

Comment: i tried this way too but not working, issue is that i am getting this type of long sentences and i have to break them in parts like i have to get part before "Company:, Manufacturer:, Number:" etc. So i tried explode but not working